# Git commit made all my files disappear?

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to this Git thing.
I tried to commit my work, using commit amend inside GitX (cause I wanted to make only 1 final commit).

I pulled the latest source, resolved conflicts, then staged and commited amend again.

However, now I notice that lots of new files that I created no longer appear on the file system anymore, and they are not listed on the files to commit in GitX.

maybe it's something wrong I did after I resolved conflicts, dunno.
How do I get my files back ? I want to upload them to remote server.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can give us a list of exactly what you did.

Comment: Does that look like http://www.randyfay.com/node/89 ?

Comment: It sure sounds like you did something that you didn't tell us about. Did you possibly have some `checkout`s in there somewhere? Maybe you committed on a different branch, or even with detached HEAD? And why are you using `commit --amend` all the time? Especially during a merge, it makes no sense.

Comment: Actually I was on a branch, and I noticed that after I pulled the latest changes, resolved conflicts, and then committed again,  it actually forced me out of the branch (to a situation where I was in no branch at all). only after I "rebase -continue" it let me in again. I tried checking out other branched to see if my files were there, but nothing helped. is there a way to see previous commits even if I ammended them ? I need to get my previous files back to life

Comment: and what does it mean detached head ? I might have done stupid thing which I'm not aware of :).   I commit ammend cause I though that's the way to force just one final commit before I push to the server.

Comment: @Idan if you want to upload one commit, just commit normally, then squash all your commits into one using rebase squash. That way, during development you have your whole history, but you still only upload one commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git rebase --continue , after resolving the conflicts did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you force resolved the conflicts, it will pull HEAD into the last repository, if the files weren't in HEAD they will be removed which is the heuristic for force resolving. Also note that after commiting locally, you need to 'git push' to push the commits you have to a remote tracking branch.

Comment: I'm not sure how you "force" resolve it, I just edited the problamatic file, then staged, and commit ammended this file and all the rest. then I rebase -- conitnued , and push to the server. what did I do wrong ?